# How to fix 'missing) after argument list' error in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function

Why is this giving me this error?

```
<script>
    function loadImg() {
        var imageChosen = document.getElementById('imageChosen').value.replace("C:\fakepath\","");
        alert(imageChosen);
        document.getElementById('image').src = imageChosen;
    }
</script>
```

I expect the image with id "image" to show the chosen image.

Comment: The first argument to `replace()` should be `/C:\\fakepath\\/` or `"C:\\fakepath\\"`

Comment: JS strings use `\\` to escape special characters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The value in your call to `replace()` is not escaped properly.
The value should instead be:
`"C:\\fakepath\\",""`

Read more about escaping strings [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Escape_notation)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to the escape string character \ (backslash)

When using strings in Javascript we may escape some character in the string. For example a break line (\n) or even a "(double quotes) when declaring the string or even an backslash \ need a escape.

Examples:

```
x = "my \\" // Will output as the same as "my \"

z = "my \"quotes\" // Will output as 'my "quotes" '
```